# present vs past tense

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, reported-speech, present-simple

> I told her to light the lamp when it **gets** dark.

> I told her to light the lamp when it **got** dark.

Which sentence is correct? If both are correct then what is the difference in meaning between them and when to use them individually???

Comment: lamp* not lamb. And you would also like to remove the tag of reported-speech from your question.

Answer (score 0):

**I told her to light the lamb when it gets dark.**

> Means that you have told her to light the lamb whenever it gets dark.

**I told her to light the lamb when it got dark.**

> It's in the past and the action is  done and finished.